# Heroku/Django Static files

Tags: django, heroku

In my local development environment

```
href={% static "datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.css" %}/>
```

loads perfectly fine. In heroku, it says CSRF error which I think is because it is trying to load from the local host.

How do I configure my settings.py to load the static files correctly? My file structure is:

```
/project
  /app
    /staticfiles
  /mysite
```

Comment: csrf error is not part of staticfile loading. In heroku dubug - false will serve staticfile for you.

Comment: So I need to keep debug on all the time?

Comment: if `forman start` work fine. Then heroku server also works well. Can you check you can access `css` using `domain.herokuapp.com/staticfiles/datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.css`

Comment: @rajasimon When I use foreman start, everything works and loads properly. When i check access to the CSS, I CAN access it if debug is set to True, as you suggested, and I can't if debug is set to False.

Comment: The information you provide is very less. we can't dubug for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Install **dj-static** (a Django static file server) [(Getting Started with Django on Heroku)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)

Installing with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

```
pip install dj-static
```

settings.py

```
# Static asset configuration
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

wsgi.py

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```